# D3js - Add transparent gap between path in pie chart

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a simple pie chart made with d3js and I would like to add transparent gap between each path.

```
paths = pieWrap.selectAll("path")
            .data(pie(data)).enter()
            .append("path")
            .style("fill", "rgba(90, 168, 217, 1)")
            .style("stroke", "#FFF")
            .style("stroke-width", "1")
            .style("stroke-opacity", "0")
            .attr("d", arc);
```

Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/x4p0eLmL/2/

Just to know, in my case the background is an image so I can't use its color.
I tried stroke-opacity but it doesn't seem to work. 
Is there a proper way to do that with d3js?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using a fraction? http://jsfiddle.net/x4p0eLmL/4/

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't probably clear, I want the gap to be totally transparent.

Comment: can you transform each piece of the pie n-px outward from the center?

Comment: I have had the same idea as @redress suggested: http://jsfiddle.net/x4p0eLmL/9/ see `.attr("transform", function(path) {...`. It is suitable for smaller gaps between the paths. Each path is translated to outer circle with `radius+3` in the current example. There is the problem with "wider" gaps where the circle may be "distorted"

Comment: @user3714582, you should write that up as an answer, I'd upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the same idea as @redress suggested: http://jsfiddle.net/x4p0eLmL/9/. The added part is as follows:

```
.attr("transform", function(path) {
    middleAngle = -Math.PI/2 + (path.startAngle+path.endAngle)/2;
    dx = 3 * Math.cos(middleAngle);
    dy = 3 * Math.sin(middleAngle);
    return "translate("+dx+", "+dy+")";
})
```

`path` has the attributes `startAngle` and `endAngle`. There is computed middle angle and translated. It is suitable for smaller gaps between the paths. Each path is translated to outer circle with radius+3 in the current example. There is the problem with "wider" gaps where the circle may be "distorted"